# Extract all object values from array node

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, mongoose, extract

I got an array with objects and they're values.

Is it possible to extract all object values without doing this every time: `Array[objnumber].value`?

Here is how it looks in mongoDB:https://gyazo.com/a4a6702ef0546609ea231de299ee62fd

Here is what data looks like

```
{
   "date":[
      {
         "title":"Unavaible",
         "start":"2020-05-19",
         "end":"2020-05-22"
      },
      {
         "title":"Unavaible",
         "start":"2020-05-28",
         "end":"2020-05-29"
      },
      {
         "title":"Unavaible",
         "start":"2020-05-29",
         "end":"2020-05-31"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output? It is somewhat unclear to me what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I just used JSON.stringify to accomplish it.

Code:

```
const responses = response.data.date
        const stringify = JSON.stringify(responses);
        this.setState({
          undates:[stringify]
        });
```

Comment: `const stringify` should be a string, `stringify[0]` will be just the first character of that string

Comment: yep sry I forgot to change!Thx